# Class template and condition checking

Tags: c++, templates

This is probably a really obvious question but I want to be sure about it before going on with my development.

I have a templated class something like:

```
template<TypeA var1, TypeB var2>
class myClass
{
  //Attributes
  ...
  //Methods
  ...
  void checkHit(vector<Real>* path, vector<bool>* active)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      //Some process
      bool hit = ((var1 == Up) || (var1 == Down));
    }
    //...
    bool flag = ((var2 == Left) || (var2 == Right));
  }
}
```

If I create and object like

```
myClass obj<Up, Right>(...);
```

When executing the method

```
obj.checkHit( ... );
```

Will the program just check for `bool hit = ((var1 == Up)` and `(var2 == Right)` ?? In other words, will the compiler throw away the code that doesn't has to do with the template-parameters passed? What I mean is if the resulting code after compiling will be something like

```
template<TypeA var1, TypeB var2>
class myClass
{
  //Attributes
  ...
  //Methods
  ...
  void checkHit(vector<Real>* path, vector<bool>* active)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
      //Some process
      bool hit = ((var1 == Up)); //Like if I have never put "|| (var1 == Down));"
    }
    //...
    bool flag = ((var2 == Right));
  }
}
```

Hope the example is clear enough, I just simplified (a lot) the real code but it should be roughly equivalent. If it isn't clear just tell and I will gladly improve it.

Comment: `myClass obj<TypeA::Up, TypeB::Right>(...);` does not make sense.

Comment: @Nawaz my mistake, I think it makes a little more sense now.

Comment: You mean this one : `myClass obj<Up, Right>(...);`? Well, that doesn't make sense either.

Comment: Not only that one but anyways, Zac Howland made some assumptions (that are right) and answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your `TypeA` and `TypeB` are either enumerations or some sort of class/struct with those values defined?

That being the case, the compiler isn't going to "throw out" code here.  Your conditional checks to see what the template parameters are, so if they don't match what is in the conditionals, you'll end up with a call that would basically do this:

```
bool hit = (0 == 1 || 1 == 2);
```

Depending on your optimization settings, the compiler may realize that this will always be false and just set it to false (also assuming you do something useful in the function so the compiler doesn't just turn it into a noop).

You also should pass your vectors by reference (or constant reference), and I would avoid using `vector<bool>`.

Comment: Thanks I see, so more than "throwing away" is actually checking the actual values.

Answer (score 1):

The example is not really clear enough, there is no "code that doesn't has to do with the template-parameters passed" because nothing depends on `hit` or `flag`, so a decent optimizer would turn `checkHit` into a completely empty function!

The compiler can evaluate the `((var1 == TypeA::Up) || (var2 == TypeB::Down))` condition at compile-time and a decent optimizing compiler will propagate the result of that condition to the rest of the function, removing any dead code that will never be run due due to the value of that condition.

Also, do you really want to pass these arguments by value?

```
void checkHit(vector<Real> path, vector<bool> active)
```

Answer (score 0):

the Program will NOT throw away any part of the code.Template classes are only used to generalize the usage of a class .once a `typeA` and `Type B` are chosen they will all be taken as the `Type A` and `Type B` throughout the code and the rest of the code will execute in the normal way that it would without any templates